# MPI - C++ vs Python, can't compile anymore

Tags: python, c++, mpi, conda, ubuntu-18.04

I could always use mpi with C++, compiling programs via mpicxx. Some time ago, I also had to use mpi with Python. I installed the Python package mpi4py via Anaconda and my Python mpi codes worked fine.

Now, however, I went back to C++. When trying to compile with mpicxx, I get an error:

"
**mpicxx -o TEST.exe TEST.cpp**

**The Open MPI wrapper compiler was unable to find the specified compiler
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ in your PATH.
Note that this compiler was either specified at configure time or in
one of several possible environment variables.**"

Apparently, installing mpi4py with Anaconda messed something up as the system tries to look for a compiler with "conda" in its name...

Can someone guide me to fix this in a way that I can freely use both, C++ and Python, with mpi?

edit: Using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You probably need to show some more details about your setup and how you installed the tools you have installed. It took me a few seconds to guess that you were using windows and not linux, macOS or some other OS. With that said even on windows there could be several different ways to install and use these tools.

Comment: Conda is an invasive species. Before you do anything that does not involve conda, explicitly "conda deactivate".

Comment: Hi guys, I am indeed using Linux (Ubuntu 18.04). Thanks for the hint with deactivating conda before doing anything else, will keep it in mind for the future. Should I uninstall Anaconda ?